# Why does Xcode have fonts that do not show up in UIViews in xib or storyboard?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, fonts, nsattributedstring

Trying to style my UILabel, in Attributes Inspector I set the font of my attributed text to `Apple Chancery`. In the preview window it shows correctly, but in the UIView itself the font is not applying. And when I try running the device just in case, the font still does not show. If I change the font to something else, this "something else" shows. So is there a known problem with iPhone simulators and devices not showing certain fonts that are in fact available in Xcode? I am using Xcode-6

Answer (score 0):

Xcode displays fonts found in the Mac, not on the actual iOS device. Before selecting a font, you should make sure it is available on iOS devices.

Sites such as http://iosfonts.com/ or even trial and error can help.

Answer (score 0):

Apple Chancery is only present in Mac OS X, but you can load ttf programmatically (see [Google](https://www.google.fr/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Apple%20Chancery&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=N_c_VLbGC4iX-AbTh4GAAQ) for the ttf) :

(I don't know if you are allowed to use this font via ttf, see the font license)

1. Copy the ttf to your Xcode project
2. Link your UILabel to your source code
3. Then, set custom font :

   ```
   [myLabel setFont: [UIFont fontWithName:@"Apple Chancery" size:15]];
   ```